# Using Outlook API's with M language (Power query, power BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to move emails from one folder to another folder in an outlook shared mailbox through Power Query (M Language) using Outlook APIs. Microsoft has mentioned the syntax in their website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#MoveCopyMessages

I build a syntax as per a few other sources but I'm not able to move the emails

```
let
    url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{MessageID}/move",
    body = "{""DestinationId"": ""DeletedItems""}",

    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[ Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body) ] ))

in
    Source
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong in the above syntax

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I would not use M or Power Query to move messages from one folder to another. It is designed to extract data into a tablaur format. Power shell or Python or JavaScript is far more suited to this task

Comment: @mkRabbani - Thanks fr your response! This is the error I see. DataSource.Error: Web. Contents with the Content option is only supported when connecting anonymously. I assume the syntax is not right.

Comment: @Jon - Thanks for the response! We are using .Net to do all the outlook operations (Read\Move\Copy etc.). We run the jobs throughout the day, which means we use an application to run the .net code throughout the day to monitor outlook emails and move them to different folders based on validations. We've been facing a few issues with it lately. So, trying to see if the power query does the job. I'm able to pull the emails through power query but trying to work investigate options to taking actions on the emails (Reply\Movce\Copy etc..) through PowerQuery\VBA or any excel related tools.